# Powershell's $profile analog for regular windows command line (cmd.exe)

Tags: powershell, cmd

Powershell's $profile is very convenient to add frequently used commands. How can I do the same in cmd.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real equivalent to PowerShell's `$profile` for `CMD`. However, some customization can be done with an AutoRun script. Add a new `REG_SZ` (or `REG_EXPAND_SZ`) value `AutoRun` with the path to your script to `[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]`, e.g. like this:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "C:\path\to\your\init.cmd"
```

I normally use an `init.cmd` like this:

```
@echo off
doskey /insert /macrofile=%USERPROFILE%\macro.def
```

with `macro.def` containing my aliases:

```
.="%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" /e,.
..=cd ..
ls=dir /d $*
ll=dir /x $*
```

Comment: You could also achieve similar functionality by creating a shortcut to CMD.EXE in which the command line is something like: `cmd /k "C:\path\to\your\init.cmd"`. The /k parameter tells CMD to execute the specified command and then accept input from the keyboard (whereas /C tell cmd.exe to execute the specified command and then terminate). It's probably more robust to do use the registry mod in the answer, but if you don't want to modify your registry this is an alternative.  You could also use this method to set up multiple CMD.EXE shortcuts, each with its own init script.

Answer (score 0):

The PATH environment variable would provide visibility to "commands" in the form of executable modules (including batch files).  There's also AUTOEXEC.BAT that is run when the OS starts up, but that's not quite what you're looking for.

There isn't a "profile" script that's run in cmd.exe sessions in a similar way to how $profile scripts are run in PowerShell, though.